# Adding New Linear Feature using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing

I am new to QGIS (2.6.1) and am having trouble adding a new linear feature to an existing layer.

I have set tolerances and digitized the vertices of the line and it terminates with a large green X at the terminal node.  But any attempt to select the feature results in 0 features found. And if I turn off the layer, this solitary line remains visible.  What layer is the line associated with?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is associated with the layer you have switched to `Edit` mode before digitizing.

Once you have saved and left the edit mode, the feature should be selectable if you have selected the layer in the table of content.